# Crystal XI - Exctracting portion of a string

Tags: string, extract, crystal-reports-xi

How do I extract the text in the last set of brackets (including the brackets) from a string with `Crystal` syntax?

String example:

```
"Coaching (CG) and Mentoring (MG) (SST)"
```

The result should be:

```
(SST)
```

//I am using this formula:

```
right({LMS_sch_Course_Table.NamePrimary},(len({LMS_sch_Course_Table.NamePrimary})-instr({LMS_sch_Course_Table.NamePrimary}," ("))+1)
```

//unfortunatley it gives me "(CG) and Mentoring (MG) (SST)"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Right("Coaching (CG) and Mentoring (MG) (SST)",5)
```

Edit----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Local Stringvar x:=databasefield;
Local Numbervar i;
Local Stringvar y;
Local Stringvar Array z:=(Split (x," "));

for  i:=1 to count(z) do
(
if("(" in z[i])
then
y:=z[i]
);

y;
```

Comment: "Coaching (CG) and Mentoring (MG) (SST)" is an example of the problem I am having with more than one set of brackets in it. My formula (in my initial post) picks up everything from the right to the first bracket in the string and I only want the last bracket and its value, which can be anything from 2-10 characters.

Comment: To the extent I understand you need only those values that are in brackets from the complete string?

Comment: No I only need the very last brackets in the string including their value - every sting finishes with  "text (something)". However, the value in the last bracket can be anywhere from 2-8 characters) That's why I cant use the Right function.

Thanks for your code snippet Siva. It still gives me this as a result:  "(MG(SST)" form the string "Coaching (CG) and Mentoring (MG) (SST)"

---so I am only looking for (SST)

Comment: @Nancy hauser Edited my answer...plz check and let me know incase any issue